# Install Ubuntu 12.04 step 4

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot

When I get to step 4 of installation process, I'm not being given the option to 'Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7' (which is the option I want). Instead I'm presented with the option of it being my only operating system or 'Something else'. If I select 'something else' I'm presented with a scary list of options. How do I get to being able to having Ubuntu installed alongside Windows 7?

I have a new Lenovo Thinkpad T430.

Comment: Make an empty partition. Select something else the last option and install in the unallocated partition

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide any guidance on how I go about doing that? I'm in unknown territory.

Answer (score 2):

> Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7

this option will ONLY show if you have UNALLOCATED space. Free up space from within windows (so you need to shrink a partition; partition magic can do this, [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) can do this too but a native windows application might suit you better for this one time only action), leave the newly freed space un-formatted and then re-run the installer.

At present both options (replace windows and something else) will destroy data you might want to keep.